# Pass "function with parameter" as parameter

Tags: swift

This doesn't compile

```
func showAlert(_ title: String, message: String, 
  onOk: (()->())? = nil,
  onAnotherAction:((anotherActionTitle : String)-> Void)? = nil) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in
        onOk?()
    }

    let anotherAction = UIAlertAction(title: anotherActionTitle, style: .default) { (action) in
        onAnotherAction?()
    }

    alertController.addAction(ok)
    alertController.addAction(anotherAction)

    ...
}
```

This compiles

```
func showAlert(_ title: String, message: String,
  onOk: (()->())? = nil,
  onAnotherAction:((String)-> Void)? = nil)
```

However, I have to declare another parameter for the title *anotherActionTitle* of *onAnotherAction()*.

Is there a way make the first approach work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I have to declare another parameter for the title `anotherActionTitle` of `onAnotherAction()`

No, you don't have to do that. Just make it a normal parameter of the function as a whole:

```
func showAlert(_ title: String, message: String,
               onOk: (()->())? = nil,
               anotherActionTitle: String? = nil,
               onAnotherAction: (()->())? = nil) {
```

The rest of your function will then compile and work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since the implementation of [SE-0111](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md) as part of Swift 3, it is no longer possible to have named parameters for closure types.

There is a conceptual roadmap that the Swift core team has laid out for restoring named closure parameters at some point in the future, but no timeline for implementation that I am aware of:

https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160711/024331.html